# Linkedin API Error {"error_description":"the client is not authorized","error":"unauthorized_client"}

Tags: python, json, api, flask, linkedin-api

When I try to submit my form from python flask to linkedin I get the following exception: {"error_description":"the client is not authorized","error":"unauthorized_client"}
I've checked the code and everything should be working.

```
    post = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": os.environ["REDIRECT_URI"],
        "client_id": os.environ["API_KEY"],
        "client_secret": os.environ["API_SECRET"]
    }
    access = requests.post("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken", data=post)
    return access.text + str(post)
```

All of my environment variables appear to be correct.  (I've checked multiple times) but I'm still getting the same error.  I have already registered the app on linkedin as well and have been strictly following the documentation.  Anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It's possible your Python library is not sending the POSTed data in the correct format.  Check out Step 3 in this document:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2.  Note the x-www-form-urlencoded header requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't with the access codes but with the REDIRECT_URI.  I had it previously encoded for the get request so that it'd be in the proper formula for that.  However that format doesn't work the same for a POST request.  Rather than https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Flinkedin it needs to be formatted https://www.example.com/linkedin. This is because the request library will escape the parameters, and if it's already escaped it will become double-escaped.